# update multiple columns using case statement in sql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
select @calc
update UserTransaction set DP=(case 
when (TotalBV >= 201 and TotalBV < 600) then (0.1*TotalBV)
when (TotalBV >= 601 and  TotalBV <1600 ) then (0.15*TotalBV)
when (TotalBV >= 1601 and  TotalBV< 5000) then (0.18*TotalBV)
when (TotalBV >= 5001 and TotalBV< 15000) then (0.21*TotalBV)
when (TotalBV >= 15001 and TotalBV< 30000) then (0.24*TotalBV)
when (TotalBV >= 30001 and TotalBV< 50000) then (0.27*TotalBV)
when (TotalBV >= 50001) then (0.30*TotalPBV)
else null end)
where User_Id=@UserId and Sponsor_Id=@SponsorId
```

Above is the update query I am using.Right now it is updating only one row with the specific User_Id and Sponsor_Id.How will I check this for multiple User_Id and Sponsor_Id at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Equal to operator use IN clause

```
UPDATE UserTransaction
set    DP=(CASE .. END)
WHERE  user_id IN 
       (SELECT user_id 
          FROM   TABLE) 
AND    sponsorid IN 
       (SELECT sponsorid 
          FROM   TABLE)
```

Comment: Thanks,how can I use this if I want to do the same for multiple users at the same time?